# How to delete shared folder in Ubuntu Samba

Tags: samba, smb

I created 3-4 folder for sharing and now ı want to delete one of them, I deleted folder from smb.conf file but still I can use this folder. How I delete?

Comment: After removing the storage location from the configuration file, did you restart Samba? What OS is/are the client(s) using? Windows will cache Samba locations for quite a while regardless of their continued existence.

Comment: @matigo Yes I removed and restarted Samba. My Server Machine OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and Clients are windows 10. I just deleted from smb.conf file

Comment: Ubuntu 18 Server or Ubuntu 18 Desktop used as a server? You may have created shares through the file manager. Look at `/var/lib/samba/usershares`. You may have shares defined there.

Comment: @Morbius1 Yes I used ubuntu 18.04 desktop as a server. Thank you for comment. It really helps me